# Javascript Make For Loop change numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code here:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){
        if ( bots[i].getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){  
            var executed = false;
            bots[i].createDeposit({
                steamid: req.query.steamid,
                token: req.query.token,
                itemsFromThem: uniqueItems,
                message: req.query.message,
                callback: function( err, dbTradeId ){
                    if ( !executed ){
                        executed = true;
                        if ( !err && dbTradeId ){
                            res.json({ result: 1, dbTradeId: dbTradeId });   
                        } else {
                            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but',err);
                            res.json({ error: err });                    
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found(2)');
            return res.json({ error: 'Available bot not found(2)' });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that. I have there `for` loop, but I  can't get passed `if` but the bot has enough length. Is it like, if one is gonna fail it's not gonna test for others and if it's like that is there a way to do it that, if one fails it will try another and if it succeeds then it won't try.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `return` will break the loop in your else statement.

try using an array to add the messages, then after the loop exits call that array.

something like

```
var myMessages = [];
for(var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){
    if ( bots[i].getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){  
    // your code
    }else{
      myMessages.push("error": bot[i]);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify( myMessages));
```